# Join tables when searching using Sunspot/Solr in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sunspot

I have an ActiveRecord model Products with associated Suppliers (via belongs_to/has_many association). I am using Sunspot for full-text searching. I make a search with that code:

```
@search = Products.search do
  fulltext params[:search]
end
@products = @search.results
```

But I'd like to include suppliers too, so every time I call, for example,

```
@products.first.supplier
```

it wouldn't make a new request to the database. I tried to use

```
@search = Products.search(include: :supplier) do
```

but it didn't help. Is there any possible way to do that in Sunspot?

Comment: I just tried this myself in the console on my own project and it works. You can even have more than one include; you give it an array. Try it in your console where you can see the query:

    Productions.search(include: :supplier){ |s| s.keywords 'your product' }

and see if it works there.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this 
@search = Sunspot.search[Products, Supplier] do
   .....
end